# Custom Form Block not displaying

Tags: 7, forms, blocks, webforms

I'm trying to create a custom form displayed inside of a block.
[edited]

```
 <?php  

function edit_node_block_info(){
    $blocks['edit_node'] = array(
        'info' => t('Custom Block to allow edit/delete/copy'),
        'status' => 1,
        'region' => 'Primary',
        'weight' => 0,
        'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
    );

    return $blocks;
}
/*
 * Implements hook_block_view: sets how the block is displayed
 */
function edit_node_block_view($delta = ''){
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'edit_node' :
            $block['subject'] = t('Edit Nodes');
            $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('edit_node_form');
            break;
    }
    return $block;
}
/*
 * implements custom form/creating custom form for drupal_get_form named above.
 */

function edit_node_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['node-id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Enter the Node ID'),
        '#max-length' => 8,
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['edit-node'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('Select Action'),
        '#options' => array(t('edit'), t('delete'), t('copy')),
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function edit_node_form_validate($form, &$form_state, $node){
    if ($form_state['values']['node-id'] != $node->nid){
        form_set_error('node-id', 'Node-id must match a current nid.');
    }
```

I see my block in the blocks list. But, my form is not showing up. I am wondering if I need to run a `drupal_form_submit('edit_node_form', $form_state);` at the end, but shouldn't that be ran during a submit function?

I'm also wondering if I need to update the form_state as I'm not creating a form_id currently (eg https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

```
if (isset($form['type']) && $form['type']['#value'] . '_node_settings' == $form_id) {
    $form['workflow']['upload_' . $form['type']['#value']] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => t('Attachments'),
      '#default_value' => variable_get('upload_' . $form['type']['#value'], 1),
      '#options' => array(t('Disabled'), t('Enabled')),
```

But I think that is related to hook_form_alter which I have not called.

Comment: I just got it working by changing the page's it was viewable on. Not really sure why that fixed the issue, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working by changing the page's it was viewable on. Not really sure why that fixed the issue, but it did.